# can't bind "vm" notation on submit form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried to use "VM" convention on angular. But got a problem when submitting the form.

```
function loginCtrl($scope, $window, $location, Auth) {
     var vm = this;
     vm.doLogin = function(){
         var data = angular.copy(vm);
         console.log(data);

}
```

My Html:

```
 <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="loginCtrl as login">
        <form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" ng-submit="login.doLogin()">

            <div class="form-group ">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Username" ng-model="login.email">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password" ng-model="login.password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button ladda="login.loading" class="btn btn-pink btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
                        Log In </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

If I change

```
  vm.doLogin to $scope.doLogin
```

it works perfectly with print the log.

But when i use vm.doLogin it nothing happens. The form won't submit.
I've tried change the

```
  ng-submit to doLogin() without "login."
```

still not working.

How can I still use vm.doLogin without using $scope ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5t0vdyLd/  this is mostly the same your code,but added the  <body ng-app="myApp"> and module('myApp',[]). it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/a94v2u76/
JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('loginCtrl', loginCtrl);
function loginCtrl($scope, $window, $location) {
 var vm = this;
 vm.doLogin = function(user){
     console.log(user);         
  }
}
```

html

```
 <div ng-app='myApp'>
 <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="loginCtrl as login">
 <form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" ng-submit="login.doLogin(user)">
   <div class="form-group ">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.email">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
         <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button ladda="login.loading" class="btn btn-pink btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Log In </button>
     </div>
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

hope this may help you

Comment: at fiddle is working. looks like there's something wrong with mine. It's not working. hmm.. $scope is working.